# Suggestion needed on updating software available on Ubuntu 14.04 LTE

Tags: update-manager, sync, repository

Currently I am syncing repo on my laptop running on Ubuntu 14.04 LTE. I got a message that software updates are available amounting to around 340 MB. Should I update now, while the repo syncing continues? Or, should I wait the syncing to get finished first? My concern is : will updating the software interfere with the process of syncing repo? I had to delete around 74 GB of data (inside .repo folder) due to my mistake of not syncing inside my working folder and I can not afford to loose data again and start from the scratch again. Please suggest.

Comment: By repo sync you mean you are downloading android source tree ?

Comment: Yes it is building from source. I am not well conversant with Ubuntu. Neither with building Cyanogenmod from source. I am only following some guides to make a CWM(Clockworkmod) recovery for an android mobile.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will allow distro release update while your repos are still syncing.
Anyway, the safest way i applied last night itself was to download that 340MB update and then go for release update (741MB). Happily enjoying Ubuntu 14.04LTS now.

Comment: [Note]: Ensure that /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades includes Prompt=normal